# Why does this code segment return null under heavy load?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, endpoint

```
if (this.UserManagmentType != UserMgmtType.NONE)
{
   return (User)GetUserBaseById(userId);
}

if (this.UserManagmentType != UserMgmtType.NONE)
{
   return GetUserBaseById(userId) as User;
}
```

I understand the difference between casts. The first if statement should throw an invalid cast exception if the cast fails, while the second will return a null.

My question is, **for identical data under heavy load** in a multi-threaded environment, why does the first if statement occasionally return a null, while the second if statement will always return valid data?

The other item of note is that the containing method is a WCF endpoint.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, given the code you've posted, is: it won't.

The first snippet will return `null` if (and only if) `GetUserBaseById` returns null. The second will return `null` if the method's return is `null` *or* if it's not a `User` object. That behaviour doesn't change under heavy load.

If you're seeing different results under heavy load as you describe then I'd suggest you have a multithreading issue elsewhere in your code, and it just happens that this is where you're seeing the effects. This sort of bug can be very sensitive to external conditions, and you're not guaranteed that it will reproduce the same way each time you run (because it might be sensitive to, e.g., disk contention with other processes).

I would suggest a thorough review of the multithreaded functionality in question: the problem you're seeing is not in that line of code.

Comment: I agree that the problem is elsewhere, I'm curious as to why that minor change "fixed" it, because using AS got rid of the null object return.  I may end up looking at some disassembly, just to see how the two differ and hopefully glean some insight.

Comment: It didn't *really* fix it, and it's not that the change to `as` made a direct difference - I would bet money on the disassembly being a waste of your time (at least in terms of solving this problem). But perhaps the faster cast may have affected thread scheduling, thus affecting the results of other code (plus, remember that no two tests are ever the same when it comes to edgy race conditions). My advice would be to accept that it's only "fixed" by coincidence, and look into `GetUserBaseById` to work out why that's returning `null` under load.

Comment: The simplest test to prove this is the case: put a line of logging into `GetUserBaseById`: `if (returnValue == null) Log("NULL RETURN VALUE")` and run your load test again. When you repro the bug, see what the log contains.

Answer (score 0):

Two castings are different, and as per this article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8052/Type-casting-impact-over-execution-performance-in

using as keyword is faster, and I assume this has something to do with returning value always compared to prefix casting.

However I think you need to double check how you have implement `GetUserBaseById(userId)` method as I suspect it might not properly implemented for multithreaded environment.